# Best way to use rake jasmine:ci in continuous integration?

Tags: continuous-integration, rake, jasmine

I've read of some hacks where you can use NokoGiri to save html of your rails application and then using this as a template to read into your rake jasmine:ci tests and somehow use that as if you were in your rails application, and then the specs run as they normally do in continuous integration on, say Hudson.  Is there a better way of running rake jasmine:ci in continuous integration?